# when a value is selected in select, another select appears, if the first value is changed, the select dissapears

Tags: php, html-select

I'm trying find out how i can show a "select" field when a value is selected from the first "select"

Lets say

1st select area

```
<label>Transfer Type</label>
<select name="type">`
    <option value="1">Airport to Resort</option>
    <option value="2">Resort to Airport</option>
</select>
```

2nd select area

```
<label>Arrival Airport</label>
<select name="Aairport">
    <option value="1">X Airport</option>
    <option value="2">Y Airport</option>
</select>
```

3rd select area

```
<label>Arrival Resort</label>
<select name="resort">
    <option value="1">Hilton Paris</option>
    <option value="2">Sheraton Paris</option>
</select>
```

This is the default view. If the selected value is "Resort to Airport" in the first "select" section than the 2nd select should disappear and below select should appear.

```
<label>Departure Airport</label>
<select name="Dairport">
<option value="1">X Airport</option>
    <option value="2">Y Airport</option>
</select>
```

after "Departure Airport" select

the 3rd select area should remain same.

Thanks

Comment: This is a job for JavaScript, not PHP: once the user's browser gets hold of the page, PHP has no further access, or ability to interact with, it. So we need to know whether or not you're able to accept JavaScript solutions.

Comment: javascript is ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have a jQuery solution. Very simple using hidden div's that get shown on the change event of a select box.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/73j5z/2/)

Very simple:

```
$("#type").on("change", function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).val() === "0") {
         $("#AairportContainer").addClass("ui-helper-hidden");
    } else {
         $("#AairportContainer").removeClass("ui-helper-hidden");
    }      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A plain JavaScript approach is possible, though it does require a relatively up-to-date browser, due to the use of `document.querySelector()`:

```
function selectToggle(source, map) {
    var opts = source.options,
        index = source.selectedIndex,
        id, cur;
    for (var i = 0, len = opts.length; i < len; i++){
        id = map[opts[i].value];
        cur = document.querySelector('#' + id);
        cur.style.display = i === index ? 'inline-block' : 'none';
        document.querySelector('label[for="' + id + '"]').style.display = i === index ? 'inline-block' : 'none';
    }
}

var el = document.getElementById('type'),
    map = {
        1: 'aairport',
        2: 'dairport'
    };
el.onchange = function () {
    selectToggle(this, map);
};
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/j3rLB/1/).

The above is coupled with the HTML:

```
<label for="type">Transfer Type</label>
<select name="type" id="type">`
    <option value="1">Airport to Resort</option>
    <option value="2">Resort to Airport</option>
</select>
<label for="aairport">Arrival Airport</label>
<select name="aairport" id="aairport">
    <option value="1">X Airport</option>
    <option value="2">Y Airport</option>
</select>
<label for="dairport">Departure Airport</label>
<select name="Dairport" id="dairport">
    <option value="1">X Airport</option>
    <option value="2">Y Airport</option>
</select>
<label for="resort">Arrival Resort</label>
<select name="resort" id="resort">
    <option value="1">Hilton Paris</option>
    <option value="2">Sheraton Paris</option>
</select>
```

And the CSS:

```
label, select {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
}
select + label {
    clear: left;
}
label {
    width: 8em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    text-align: right;
}
label::after {
    content:': ';
}

#dairport,
label[for=dairport] {
    display: none;
}
```

With jQuery (to demonstrate the relative simplicity of using a library), it's simplified slightly:

```
var el = document.getElementById('type'),
    map = {
        1: 'aairport',
        2: 'dairport'
    };

$('#dairport, label[for="dairport"]').hide();
$('#type').change(function(){
    var that = this;
    $('.toggles').toggle(function(){
        var self = this,
            test = map[that.selectedIndex + 1];
        return (this.id && this.id == test) || (this.htmlFor && this.htmlFor == test);
    });
})
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/j3rLB/3/).

With slightly amended HTML to add a class-name:

```
<label for="type">Transfer Type</label>
<select name="type" id="type">`
    <option value="1">Airport to Resort</option>
    <option value="2">Resort to Airport</option>
</select>
<label for="aairport" class="toggles">Arrival Airport</label>
<select name="aairport" id="aairport" class="toggles">
    <option value="1">X Airport</option>
    <option value="2">Y Airport</option>
</select>
<label for="dairport" class="toggles">Departure Airport</label>
<select name="Dairport" id="dairport" class="toggles">
    <option value="1">X Airport</option>
    <option value="2">Y Airport</option>
</select>
<label for="resort">Arrival Resort</label>
<select name="resort" id="resort">
    <option value="1">Hilton Paris</option>
    <option value="2">Sheraton Paris</option>
</select>
```

References:

- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector).

Answer (score -1):

if i onderstand you right you want to let the script do something when you select all fields?
try to use js ansd jquery than you can let do something on select or not select.. and ajax to load php info

edit: use something like this(it is jQuery)

```
$('input').click(function() {
   if($('input[name=type]').is(':checked') && $('input[name=Aairport]').is(':checked')) { 
       //AJAX
    }
});
```

Comment: yes. i have found a js script, `script type="text/javascript">
function xxx(el) {
  var selectedValue = el.value;
  if(selectedValue == "Matchcode")
    document.getElementById("Types").style.display = "";

}</script>` and the `<select name="type" id="type" onChange="xxx(this);">`   but there is a problem with this code, it hides the second select and brings the hidden one to visible but if i change the 1st select back to "airport to resort" it does not go back to original "selects"